# Spring web and tomcat with https

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a web application that is running in tomcat, and i want it to used HTTPS instead of HTTP. I've created a self signed certificate so the server can use it for authentication during the handshake.
The thing is, i can't seem to get it running in https, **although when i try to access tomcat home it works fine with https.**

I've configured my **server.xml**

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />




<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="c:\Users\keystore" 
               keystorePass="testing"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I am using spring web. I am missing something?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a few months ago. Try to add this to your **web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Project Name</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Comment: Why? What does it do? I can't tell from your answer.